# <p> element appear and disappear error

Tags: javascript, jquery

The `#password-error` element below, fadeIn and hide again very fast with no reason. Does anyone know why?

```
$(function(){

     $('#password-error').hide();

     $('#submit').on('click', function(){
     if ($('#password').val() != $('#password2').val()){
          $('#password-error').show();
     }
     else{
          $('#password-error').hide();
     }
     });
});
```

Comment: Is `#submit` a submit input that is causing the form to be submitted?

Comment: Are you preventing the form from being submitted when the validation fails?

Comment: @Stryner no i don't, but i don't think this associated with the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `#submit` is a button in a form you have to make sure to prevent the default behavior of the form (Form Submit):

```
jQuery(function($) {
   $('#password-error').hide();
   $('#submit').on('click', function(event) {
     if ($('#password').val() != $('#password2').val()) {
       $('#password-error').show();
       event.stopPropagation(); // Stops the event to bubble to the form
     }
     else {
       $('#password-error').hide();
     }
   });
});
```

You might want to consider binding the listener on the form directly - to make sure your validation is triggered even if a user presses enter in the field:

```
jQuery(function($) {
   $('#password-error').hide();
   //$(myForm).on('submit', function(event) {
   $('#submit').closest('form').on('submit', function(event) {
     if ($('#password').val() != $('#password2').val()) {
       $('#password-error').show();
       event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default behavior of the form.
     }
     else {
       $('#password-error').hide();
     }
   });
});
```

Comment: You second method worked, but i cannot understand how this prevents `$('#password-error')` elemets's functionality

Comment: You are listening to the `submit` event on the form. On the event object (`event`) there is a method that will prevent the default functionality of that form (Which is submitting) `event.preventDefault();`